# Error reading .xls file with format_from_signature NA in R

Tags: r, excel, xml, xls, readxl

I have a .xls file which is sent to me daily and I'd like to automate the handling I do with it through R.

When I try to read the file using  `read_xls`, it throws the following error  `libxls error: Unable to open file`. For anyone with knowledge of Excel, this is one of those files that, when you try to open it there, Excel warns you about it not matching the file format and the extension. This, along with the fact that using  `format_from_signature` on the file returns `NA`, tells me that the file isn't a real .xls file but rather a *forced* .xls document.

I can fix the issue for a single file by just opening it on Excel and saving it as a normal .xlsx, the problem is doing it frequently. I would like to replicate that process but all in R to automate it.

**Edit:** I've added an [Excel file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kM5h4LIk-SGWGf09wpaKaLnqiy71qOim/view?usp=sharing) that meets the criteria I'm describing.

Comment: I am afraid this question would be difficult to answer without an example.

Comment: Hi @Ronak Shah, I've edited my post to provide an example, maybe with this you can help me find a solution. Thanks

Comment: Yeah...cannot read the file. I think this is related to this issue https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/598 . How did you create this file?

Comment: I just created an Excel file, saved it as a XML Spreadsheet and then changed its extension from .xml to .xls